# JNI invocation fails with UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I'm getting UnsatisfiedLinkError when invoking C functions from JNI though my setup seems correct. Here's what I've done:

There's a Java class:

```
package com.mycompany.myproduct;

public class Foo {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("external");
    }

    public void native do_foo();
}
```

I've placed `libexternal.so` to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, compiled the class, and executed `javah` over it. Resulting `com_mycompany_myproduct_Foo.h` file:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class com_mycompany_myproduct_Foo */

#ifndef _Included_com_mycompany_myproduct_Foo
#define _Included_com_mycompany_myproduct_Foo
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_com_mycompany_myproduct_Foo
 * Method:    do_foo
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_mycompany_myproduct_Foo_do_1foo(JNIEnv *, jobject);
```

Implemented a C delegation in `ctinative.c` (not sure if `extern "C"` is needed there):

```
#include "com_mycompany_myproduct_Foo.h"

#include "External.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/*
 * Class:     com_com_mycompany_myproduct_Foo
 * Method:    do_foo
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_mycompany_myproduct_Foo_do_1foo(JNIEnv *, jobject) {
    do_foo();   // this is a function that defined in External.h
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Compiled that and got `ctinative.o`:

```
gcc -x c -g -m64 -DUNIX=1 -DUSE_SBUF=1 -DMAIN_VERSION=0 -DC_VER=7 -I$(EXTERNAL_SDK_ROOT)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux -o ctinative.o -c ctinative.c
```

Here's the output of `nm ctinative.o` (is having `U` there normal?):

```
0000000000000000 T Java_com_mycompany_myproduct_Foo_do_1foo
                 U do_foo
```

Placed that `ctinative.o` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Now when invoking `Foo.do_foo()` I'm getting UnsatisfiedLinkError:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.mycompany.myproduct.Foo.do_foo()V
at com.mycompany.myproduct.Foo.do_foo(Native Method)
```

If I remove `ctinative.o` from `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` the error does not change. If I remove `libexternal.so` from `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` then of course I'm getting:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no external in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1734)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
at com.mycompany.myproduct.Foo.<clinit>
```

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: One Try : Lets check it by explicitly supplying the lib path either pass it with this way `-Djava.library.path=/YOUR/PATH/TOLIB/DIR/` or supply full path in `loadLibrary()`, let me know the result

Comment: What code, if any, is in libexternal.so?

Comment: @spong: External.h that I'm including in my C implementation file is the header file for libexternal.so. Among other things, it declares the C function do_foo() that I'm trying to invoke. Have a look at the C implementation of Java_com_mycompany_myproduct_Foo_do_1foo() function in the question

Comment: @org.life.java: replaced System.loadLibrary("external") with System.load("/home/user/shared/lib/libexternal.so") (note the different method name) and the same error is still there

Comment: It should work if everything else is  OK, one more try :)  , compare your implementation with http://cnd.netbeans.org/docs/jni/nb6-linux/beginning-jni-linux.html and try to figure out the issue

Comment: @org.life.java: I have a bit more complicated setup here: I'm calling an external library from my C implementation (which, in turn, is based on the generated .h file), so I have different compiler and linker flags, of course. From Java side everything looks the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, my experience with native libraries on Linux is limited to toy tests, however I have used them pretty extensively on Windows.  I expect the mechanism is similar, but proceed with caution :)

Java ends up calling the `Java_com_mycompany_myproduct_Foo_do_1foo()` native function when you execute the method `fooInstance.do_foo()`.  This is the native function that needs to be defined in `libexternal.so` (or whatever you choose to load with `loadLibrary()`).

If I understand your question correctly, you have compiled the function `Java_com_mycompany_myproduct_Foo_do_1foo()` into `ctinative.o`, and the implementation does not appear in `libexternal.so`.  You can check this with `objdump --dynamic-reloc libexternal.so`.

I believe you need to have your native implementation of `Java_com_mycompany_myproduct_Foo_do_1foo()` compiled into `libexternal.so`, or alternatively you could link `ctinative.o` to produce a dynamic link library something like `libctinative.so`.

EDIT: To join the dots, the complete mechanism would be:

1. Your java code calls `loadLibrary()` on a `.so` file that implements the function `Java_com_mycompany_myproduct_Foo_do_1foo()`.  Let's call this `libctinative.so`.
2. `libctinative.so` dynamically loads `libexternal.so` through the O/S's dynamic linking mechanism --- you don't need to do anything special to make this happen apart from compiling and linking `libctinative.so` in the right way
3. Your program runs correctly, assuming no other issues :)

Comment: Yeah, that was it. Basically, ctinative.o was just a JNI wrapper around libexternal.so. And I was invoking System.loadLibrary("external"), which does not have any JNI entry points, of course. After relinking ctinative.o to libctinative.so and invoking System.loadLibrary("ctinative") the error was gone. Sure, it's the wrapper you want to load/invoke, not the core library. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

You have Java_com_mycompany_myproduct_Foo_do_1foo() but native void do_foo(). Was do_1foo() its name when you generated the .h/.c files? If you've changed it you have to regenerate.